# Double integral with transform theorem for integrals

Tags: integration

I have a task and it is about integral :

$$\int \sin\left(\frac{x^3 +y^3}{xy}\right)\mathop{dx}\mathop{dy}$$

with set $B$ which is defined as $B:= x^2<2y,y^2 <2x$, with $x,y$ from the real numbers.

I am using this platform for the first time that's why I couldn't find the math expressions. I hope I can get a solution to compare with my solution.
I have as a result : $2\sin(2)-\sin(4)$ and I have solved this with the transformation theorem for integral with the determinant. Is this right guys?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the value of the integral is supposed to be $\color{red}{\frac13}\left[2\sin(2)-\sin(4)\right]$, correct?

Comment: Hi Dagmath. I suggest you review the MathJax basics, edit your post to include your calculation, and then tag your question as [solution-verification]. Welcome to MathStack.

Comment: MathJax information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164